# Batch: How to store command output with spaces in variable?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to make a Batch file to create windows firewall rules for an executable (for example, python). To do this, I have the following script:

```
REM ~ Open ports. Run with elevated administrator rights.
CALL :OPEN "python"
GOTO :EOF

:OPEN
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  GOTO :EOF
)
FOR /F %%i IN ('where %1') DO CALL :OPEN_PROGRAM "%1" %%i && GOTO :EOF
GOTO :EOF

:OPEN_PROGRAM
FOR %%j IN (TCP UDP) DO CALL :OPEN_PROGRAM_PORT %1 %2 "%%j"
GOTO :EOF

:OPEN_PROGRAM_PORT
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=%1 description=%1 dir=in action=allow edge=deferuser     profile=private program=%2 protocol=%3
GOTO :EOF
```

This works fine as long as there are no spaces in the path to the executable.

If there are spaces in the path, then only the part up to the spaces is put in the `%%i` variable. I tried using `'where /F %1'` , but then it still cuts the output on the space.

Is there a way to store the full output of `where %1` in a variable? (Preferably without writing it to a file)

Comment: see `for /?` specially the `tokens` keyword in `for /f` loop.pass arguments to subroutines within double quotes and get rid of them (if necessary) with `%~1` for argument 1, and so on

Comment: @elzooilogico Thanks! I think I can get somewhere using the back quotes. Will try this tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: also, I didn’t note before, shouldn’t be `call :open “python.exe”`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first advise you not to pass an filename without an extension. Doing so relies upon each of the extensions listed under `%PATHEXT%`, and you could have files named `python.com`, `python.bat`, `python.cmd`, `python.vbs`, `python.vbe`, `python.js`, `python.jse`, `python.wsf`, `python.wsh`, and `python.msc`, as well as `python.exe`. I'm sure you wouldn't want to unknowingly create firewall rules for all of those.

I would also advise that you do not use the `where` command for this. The reason being that it could return more than a single item. For example, try this, `where notepad.exe` and if memory serves, you'll probably see, `C:\WINDOWS\System32\notepad.exe`, followed by `C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe`. That is because `where.exe` searches each location in `%PATH%` in order of their listing, and returns each, as the first two entries under `%PATH%` should by default be `C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;`.

My suggestion therefore would be to use another method, which returns the first item found under `%PATH%` as opposed to all, and this should, if you've used the variable properly, return the default, *(most used)* item. The method is the `%~$PATH` variable expansion, and is documented under the help information for the `for` command, i.e. entering `for /?` at the Command Prompt.

Example Script:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Rem ~ Open ports. Run with elevated administrator rights.
"%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query HKU\S-1-5-19 1>NUL 2>&1 || (
 Echo This script must be run elevated.
 Echo Please use 'Run as administrator'
 "%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T 3 /NoBreak 1>NUL
 GoTo :EOF)
Call :OpenPorts "python.exe"
Pause
GoTo :EOF
 
:OpenPorts
For %%G In ("%~1") Do For %%H In (TCP UDP) Do (
 "%__AppDir__%netsh.exe" AdvFirewall Firewall Add Rule^
 Name="%~n1" Description="%~1" Dir=in Action=allow^
 Edge=deferuser Profile=private Program="%%~$Path:G"^
 Protocol=%%H)
Exit /B
```

I have removed all of the unnecessary `Call` commands, *(using just the one)*, and deliberately used carets to split up your super long line, for readability; *(which also allows you to include the `localport=` and/or `remoteport=` option, which I'd assume by your 'Open Ports' name you're going to want to include as a modification to the above later)*. I also took the liberty of including some code, to determine if the script was being run elevated, and display a message before closing, if it isn't.

Comment: The doublequotes around `python.exe` in the `Call` line are only required if the name of the file includes spaces or problematic characters, although I always use them for safety. The code should account for this, so the choice in this case is yours; if you want to use `Call :OpenPorts python.exe` instead, there's no modifications required. Please note, that I have made no specific provision in the above example for your target file not existing, so please don't run it using a file which you do not have in `%PATH%`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This does solve the problem! The reason these useless function calls were there is that I have taken some functionality out for clarity, so no worries, existence of the target is checked there (as well as if the firewall rules already exist). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Write the output of `where.exe` to a file, then read the file one line at a time. There is a way to do it without a temp file after the "===" line.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "XTOFIND=%~1"
SET "TEMPFILE=%TEMP%\wherelist.tmp"
IF EXIST "%TEMPFILE%" (DEL "%TEMPFILE%")

"%__appdir__%where.exe" "%XTOFIND%" >"%TEMPFILE%"

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('TYPE "%TEMPFILE%"') DO (
    ECHO CALL :OPEN_PROGRAM "%%~A" %2 "%%J"
)

IF EXIST "%TEMPFILE%" (DEL "%TEMPFILE%")

ECHO ============

SET "XTOFIND=%~1"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('"%__appdir__%where.exe" "%XTOFIND%"') DO (
    ECHO %%~A
    ECHO CALL :OPEN_PROGRAM "%%~A" %2 "%%J"
)
EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Will wait for a bit to see if there is a way to do this without writing it to a file...

Comment: Damn, I was not awake yesterday, your answer clearly states that you can do it without writing it to a file.... My apologies. In the end I solved it using Compo's answer.